# Eclipse search java different than find references

Tags: java, eclipse

With Eclipse 2020-03 right click -> references -> workspace returns results found in jar files that are more by string than type. For example.

```
public static Optional<BufferedImage> get(final File file) throws InternalError {
}
```

When 'get' is selected, right click -> references -> workspace returns methods from other classes with the name 'get'. But if I click search -> Java there I can select source, jar, etc. which seems to be only way to search just sources.

How can I make right click -> references use the same options selected in click search -> Java?

Answer (score 1):

In the Search view near the far right is a menu with 3 dots in a vertical column. It has a menu item for filters. I found that checking the 'potential matches' filters out results that are in libraries with a similar signature. See [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879247/meaning-of-ignore-potential-matches) for more information.